# jupyter notebook Linux ipywidgets not working

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
    import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
w = widgets.Dropdown(
    options={'Pen': 7732, 'Pencil': 102, 'Pad': 33331},
    description='Item:',
)
display(w)
#w.value
```

results: Dropdown(description='Item:', options={'Pen': 7732, 'Pencil': 102, 'Pad': 33331}, value=7732)

which is not a Drop Down

HI i was working in linux  jupyter notebook in Virtual enviroment

i have try solution from here
[Jupyter widget does not appear in notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47396512/jupyter-widget-does-not-appear-in-notebook)

and [Interactive Jupyter Widgets not working in Jupyter Lab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52590291/interactive-jupyter-widgets-not-working-in-jupyter-lab)

any thought?

UPdate other library i added in other CELL:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import json
import pandas as pd 
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

Comment: are you importing any other visualization module like matplotlib ?

Comment: @Pygirl. Yes i import from other CELL

Comment: Post the whole code then. What else you are importing

Comment: i have added to the edit PART thanks

Comment: jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.3.1
jupyter-console==6.0.0
jupyter-core==4.5.0
ipykernel==5.1.2
ipython==7.7.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.5.1

Can you mention your specifications by doing `pip freeze | grep <package partial name like ipy and jupy>`

Comment: package installed :

importlib-metadata==3.1.1
ipykernel==5.3.4
ipython==7.16.1
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.5.1
jedi==0.17.2

jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==6.1.7
jupyter-console==6.2.0
jupyter-core==4.7.0
jupyterlab-pygments==0.1.2
kiwisolver==1.3.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.3.3
mistune==0.8.4
mypy-extensions==0.4.3
nbclient==0.5.1
nbconvert==6.0.7
nbformat==5.0.8
nest-asyncio==1.4.3
notebook==6.1.5
numpy==1.19.4
packaging==20.7
pandas==1.1.4
pandocfilters==1.4.3
papermill==2.2.2

webencodings==0.5.1
widgetsnbextension==3.5.1